# Difference between <Link to> and <Button onClick> React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I am building a React JS app and was wondering what is the difference between returning:

```
<Link to={"/path"}><button>text</button></Link>
```

and setting

```
const history = useHistory();

const handleClick = () => {
  history.push("/path");
}
```

to return

```
<button onClick={handleClick}>text</button>
```

Cheers

Comment: SEO, semantic, crawling, and `link` allow users to *open in new tab*

Comment: also `button` tag is redundant here `<Link to={"/path"}><button>text</button></Link>`

Comment: In addtion to the other comments. Take a look at the source code: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L74

Comment: I do have a :hover css to make the button change background color so might need to keep the button in. Unless I can remove the button and still achieve it.

Comment: nevermind, :hover also works for the Link. Thanks!